# How to use grep to find strings begin with hypen(-)?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

For example:

man perl | grep '-w'

only to receive error messages

Comment: `man perl | grep -- '-w'`

Comment: man perl | grep -F "-w"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the double hyphen:

```
% man perl | grep -- '-w'                                                                                                                                                                    
       The "use warnings" pragma produces some lovely diagnostics. One can also use the -w flag, but its use is normally discouraged, because it gets applied to all executed Perl code,
```

This usage of `--` is [recommended by the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `-` character.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Could you provide some references about the usage of '--'?

Comment: @MuYuanLi: added

Answer (score 2):

or just escape `-` character:

```
man perl | grep '\-w'
```

output:

```
   also use the -w flag, but its use is normally discouraged, because it
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -- to give a parameter which starts with - .

```
MacBook-Pro:~ chen$ man perl | grep -- '-w'
       also use the -w flag, but its use is normally discouraged, because it
MacBook-Pro:~ chen$
```

In most bash builtin & some other commands, the *--* means the end of options. By the same token, you can delete a file which name is *-f.txt* using this command:

```
MacBook-Pro:tmp chen$ rm -fv -- -f.txt 
-f.txt
MacBook-Pro:tmp chen$
```

Comment: Thanks, could you provide some refferences on when and how to use '--'?

Comment: man getopt : The getopt utility will place `--' in the arguments at the end of the options, or recognize it if used explicitly.